# Problemas con linear Layout

Tags: android-studio, xml

Necesito alinear el texto "su lista" en el centro y dejar el boton a la derecha, pero usando el linearLayout, como puedo hacerlo?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="SU LISTA"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:
        />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:text="PRUEBA"
    android:background="#FFF"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega peso (android:layout_weight) a los elementos, puedes agregar el peso mayor al elemento que deseas que ocupe mas espacio que los demás, solo tendrías que "Jugar" con los tamaños

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="SU LISTA"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Texto"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: corrige tu respuesta, el Button tiene 0 en su layout_weight

Comment: Mil gracias amigo